# Software for drawing interactively via voice commands or command line interface

Tags: drawing, drawing-tablet, accessibility, technical-drawing, draw.io

I'm not sure if my post is better suited for the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. If so, then perhaps migrate it there.

How hard would it be to design a computer program where you could use voice commands or a command line interface to draw a picture, in an interactive manner?

Here is a sample of commands that could be given to the program, as it draws.

- Draw a dog.
- Longer ears.
- Make it sitting.
- Make a seagull.
- Draw a doghouse.
- Draw the sun.
- Make the seagull fly from the dog to the doghouse.
- Draw a stick.
- Place the stick under the dog's paw.

Does such software exist.

Where can I find such a program?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a **Graphic Design** question. It *might* be software recommendations, but I think even that may be a stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a text to image AI. Try:

- [Midjourney](https://www.midjourney.com)
- Stable diffusion
- Dall-E

interactivity is there but its bit slow since building the latent space is a slow operation. We arent entirely there yet.